# submit button outside a form governed by input requirements

Tags: html, angularjs, forms, button

I have a simple form with one input field

```
    <form ng-submit="UsernameModalInstance.submitUsername()">
        <input type="text" required autofocus size="25" pattern="[^\s]+" title="no spaces allowed" placeholder="Enter Username Here...">        
    </form>
```

Note: this input field does not allow for no entry or any white spaces
Thus: my ng-submit function only fires when these requirements have been met

**this is the functionality i want**

However, there is another way to submit the form!

underneath this form i have a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" title="You must enter a username to proceed" ng-click="UsernameModalInstance.submitUsername()" type="button">Submit Username</button>
```

The ng-click fires the same function as the ng-submit on the input

BUT I want this submit username button to have the same requirements as the form input.

currently, clicking the button will fire the function without meeting any of the requirements of having to enter something and no white spaces!

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: simple keep the button inside the form and give type as `submit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple example. You can use it with `ng-submit` i.e replace `onsubmit` with `ng-submit` and no need of `ng-click` if you keep the submit button inside `form` element

```js
function submitUsername(){
  console.log("valid username");
  event.preventDefault();//just to so it works here might not need in your code
}
```

```html
<form onsubmit="submitUsername()">
        <input type="text" required autofocus size="25" pattern="[^\s]+" title="no spaces allowed" placeholder="Enter Username Here...">    
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: ```<form ng-submit="UsernameModalInstance.submitUsername()">
        <input type="text" required autofocus size="25" pattern="[^\s]+" title="no spaces allowed" placeholder="Enter Username Here...">        
        <button class="btn btn-primary" title="You must enter a username to proceed" type="button">Submit Username</button>
    </form> ```

I have tried the above, but nothing is happening when i click the button, for some reason the function only fires when i press enter on the keyboard but not when clicking button, any ideas??

Comment: My bad, i forgot to change `type="button"` to `type="submit"`
all working now, thank you, answer accepted

Comment: dude i have mentioned that the button type should be `submit` try that it will work